# Google Maps : get duration between points in path

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem to get duration between geographical points .

I use the directions service: developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions
I use the javascript language.

I want to get points between a city of origin and a city of arrival. In the json response, I get steps and their duration. Each **step** has a path which contain points.
A **point** is a LatLng object which corresponds to a latitude and a longitude.
However, the response **does not contain the duration between each point** of the path.
So I get a duration between each step but **not between each point** of each step.
I want to have duration between all points.

First part of the json response:

[image: First part of the json response]

Second part of the json response:

[image: Second part of the json response]

You can see in the second picture that there is no duration and distance between each point.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: According to the [Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-directions#DirectionsResponses:~:text=value%22%3A%20135%20%7D%2C%0A%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%20%22-,duration%22%3A%20%7B%20%22text%22%3A%20%221%20min,-%22%2C%20%22value%22%3A%2024), There is a duration given to the response of each step. So I don't understand what you're issue meant.

Comment: Yes, you are right.
The step is composed of several geographical points. 
And the Directions service does not give the times and distances between these points.
I would like to have them to get very precise durations.

Comment: What I meant is that there IS duration and distance between those points according to the docs. Please edit your question to show the result that you meant so that we could take a look at it and really see your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The first drop down you showed on your sample response is the **`legs`**, then the second one is the **`steps`**.

Let me put here a brief explanation of some of the Directions results from the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-directions):

> [`routes`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-directions#DirectionsResponse-routes) - *Contains an array of routes from the origin to the destination. Routes consist of nested **`legs`** and **`steps`**.
> See [DirectionsRoute](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-directions#DirectionsRoute) for more information.*

> [`legs`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-directions#DirectionsRoute-legs) - *An array which contains information about a leg of the route, between two locations within the given route. A separate leg will be present for each waypoint or destination specified. (A route with no waypoints will contain exactly one leg within the legs array.) Each leg consists of a series of **`steps`**. See [DirectionsLeg](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-directions#DirectionsLeg) for more information.*

> [`steps`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-directions#DirectionsLeg-steps) - *An array of **`steps`** denoting information about each separate **step** of the **leg** of the journey. See [DirectionsStep](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-directions#DirectionsStep) for more information.*

With this, The Directions API on your example response is actually working as intended. The `legs` returns the total **duration** and **distance** from origin to destination. Given that you did not specifiy a waypoint. While the `steps` returns multiple ***durations*** and ***distances***.

Here's a sample response (*I minimized other results so that you could see the `legs` and `steps` better*):

[image: Sample result]

And if you notice on your sample image, it says there that the `steps` consists of 48 array results: *Array(48)*. And that's because `steps` are supposed to return multiple **distances** and **durations**.

[image: Working as intended response]

The `lat_lngs` result is not for measuring distance and duration but for generating polylines. The [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/directions#DirectionsStep.lat_lngs) says here that it is...

> *"A sequence of LatLngs describing the course of this step. This is an approximate (smoothed) path of the step."*

And it's already deprecated.

Feel free to comment if you have more questions. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations.
It is therefore impossible to have times between each point. I wanted to have extremely precise times for each step. So you have confirmed my intuition.
I wanted the duration and the distance between each LatLng of the step but you confirm that they do not allow to measure distances. 
Do you have a solution to break down the step into smaller steps and recover the durations and distances between these new steps?

Comment: Yes, steps is the smallest portion of the route result where the Maps API returns a distance and duration. You can file a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188841&template=789306) on the Public Issue Tracker if you want such feature to be on the API and let it be reviewed by Google Engineers if implementation would be possible.